# MUI DataGridPro not sorting email Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am trying to create a table using MUI DataGridPro, where sorting functionality in every field is working except the email.
Im going to add some gibberish here so that my question gets published. Please ignore the following string "jahgfhujagfyuawfqawguyfbvqwuhfgyuqwfvbiuwqegcvyuewqbvcuiwegvuyewbcvuyewgvfuyewvbyutgwevbuywevyuwebvuywebvuiywergvbywevbtgywebvuywebcvuiyqwfgvuyqwcbiqwueyfbvweiufvuewbfewuvbcieuwfvyuwefvbewyucvweuiyfgvqeuifhbeiuqwfgbiweufbyweiubviuwevfweifgvbweuybvcweuigfvuwifvwefbhueqwfviqugdfvuywefbweyuifvbuiwefgvwefgweyufbefgeuywhfbbfiew"

```
/* eslint-disable no-nested-ternary */
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
  Box,
  Grid,
  IconButton,
} from '@mui/material';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import EmailOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EmailOutlined';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { DataGridPro } from '@mui/x-data-grid-pro';
import { NavigateRoutes } from '../../../constant';
import useStyles from '../../../custom-hooks/useStyles';
import styles from '../my-class/style';
import { CustomUnsortedIcon, CustomAscendingIcon, CustomDescendingIcon } from '../../../utils/commonUiComponent';
import Constant from '../../../store/constant';
import { setLocalStorage } from '../../../utils/localStorageMethod';

export default function ListView({

  studentsData,
  checkboxChanged,
  loading,
  setError,
  setOpenDialog,
  // courseName,
}) {
  const classes = useStyles(styles)();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  localStorage.setItem('sendSingleEmail', false);
  const getMarksHeader = () => (
    <div>
      <span style={{ height: '5vh' }}>
        {t('MARKS')}
      </span>
      <div>{t('Q2')}</div>
    </div>
  );

  const getHomeworkHeader = () => (
    <div>
      <span style={{ height: '5vh', left: -14 }}>
        {t('HOMEWORK')}
      </span>
      <div>{t('Q2')}</div>
    </div>
  );

  const columns = [
    {
      field: 'studentName',
      headerName: t('STUDENT_NAME'),
      align: 'left',
      sortable: true,
      class: 'studentNameField',
      headerClassName: 'studentNameHeader',
      cellClassName: 'studentNameCell',
      renderCell: (rowValues) => (
        <Tooltip title={`${rowValues?.row?.studentInfo?.firstName} ${rowValues?.row?.studentInfo?.lastName}`}>
          <div className={classes.wrappingCell}>{`${rowValues?.row?.studentInfo?.firstName} ${rowValues?.row?.studentInfo?.lastName}`}</div>
        </Tooltip>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'parentName',
      headerName: t('PARENT_NAME'),
      align: 'left',
      sortable: true,
      headerClassName: 'parentHeader',
      cellClassName: 'parentNameCell',
      renderCell: (rowValues) => (
        <Tooltip title={`${rowValues?.row?.parent1Info?.firstName} ${rowValues?.row?.parent1Info?.lastName}`}>
          <div className={classes.wrappingCell}>{`${rowValues?.row?.parent1Info?.firstName} ${rowValues?.row?.parent1Info?.lastName}`}</div>
        </Tooltip>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'studentEmailAddress',
      headerName: t('STUDENT_EMAIL_ADDRESS'),
      sortable: true,
      align: 'left',
      headerAlign: 'left',
      headerClassName: 'studentEmailHeader',
      cellClassName: 'studentEmailCell',
      renderCell: (rowValues) => (
        <Tooltip title={`${rowValues?.row?.studentInfo?.manabadiEmail}`}>
          <div className={classes.wrappingCell}>{`${rowValues?.row?.studentInfo?.manabadiEmail}`}</div>
        </Tooltip>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'marksQ1',
      sortable: false,
      headerName: t('Q1'),
      align: 'center',
      headerClassName: 'marksHeader',
      cellClassName: 'marksCell',
      renderCell: (cellValues) => (
        <Box
          component="span"
          onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'marks', 'Q1')}
          className={cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks >= cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.passingCriteria ? classes.marksGreen
            : cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks < parseInt(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.passingCriteria, 10) - 10
              ? classes.marksRed : cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks >= parseInt(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.passingCriteria, 10) - 10
                ? classes.marksYellow : classes.marksGrey}
        >
          {cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.passingCriteria
            ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks) ? cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks : Number(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks).toFixed(2) : '-'}
          {cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.passingCriteria && !cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q1?.isAttended ? '(A)' : ''}
        </Box>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'marksQ2',
      headerName: getMarksHeader(),
      disableColumnResize: 'false',
      align: 'left',
      headerClassName: 'marksHeader',
      cellClassName: 'marksCell',
      sortable: false,
      renderCell: (cellValues) => (
        <Box
          component="span"
          onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'marks', 'Q2')}
          className={cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks >= cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.passingCriteria ? classes.marksGreen
            : cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks < parseInt(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.passingCriteria, 10) - 10
              ? classes.marksRed : cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks >= parseInt(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.passingCriteria, 10) - 10
                ? classes.marksYellow : classes.marksGrey}
        >
          {cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.passingCriteria
            ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks) ? cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks : Number(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks).toFixed(2) : '-'}
          {cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.passingCriteria && !cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q2?.isAttended ? '(A)' : ''}
        </Box>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'marksQ3',
      headerName: t('Q3'),
      headerClassName: 'marksHeader',
      align: 'left',
      cellClassName: 'marksCell',
      sortable: false,
      renderCell: (cellValues) => (
        <Box
          component="span"
          onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'marks', 'Q3')}
          className={cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks >= cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.passingCriteria
            ? classes.marksGreen
            : cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks < parseInt(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.passingCriteria, 10) - 10
              ? classes.marksRed : cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks >= parseInt(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.passingCriteria, 10) - 10
                ? classes.marksYellow : classes.marksGrey}
        >
          {cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.passingCriteria
            ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks) ? cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks : Number(cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks).toFixed(2) : '-'}
          {cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.passingCriteria && !cellValues?.row?.marks?.Q3?.isAttended ? '(A)' : ''}
        </Box>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'homeworkQ1',
      sortable: false,
      headerName: t('Q1'),
      align: 'center',
      headerClassName: 'marksHeader',
      cellClassName: 'marksCell',
      renderCell: (cellValues) => (
        <Box
          component="span"
          onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'homework', 'Q1')}
          className={cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q1?.weightage
            ? classes.homeworkColor : classes.marksGrey}
        >
          {cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q1?.weightage
            ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks) ? cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks : Number(cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q1?.obtainedMarks).toFixed(2) : '-'}
        </Box>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'homeworkQ2',
      headerName: getHomeworkHeader(),
      disableColumnResize: 'false',
      align: 'left',
      headerClassName: 'homeworkHeader',
      cellClassName: 'homeworkCell',
      sortable: false,
      renderCell: (cellValues) => (
        <Box
          component="span"
          onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'homework', 'Q2')}
          className={cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q2?.weightage
            ? classes.homeworkColor : classes.marksGrey}
        >
          {cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q2?.weightage
            ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks) ? cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks : Number(cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q2?.obtainedMarks).toFixed(2) : '-'}
        </Box>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'homeworkQ3',
      headerName: t('Q3'),
      headerClassName: 'marksHeader',
      align: 'left',
      cellClassName: 'marksCell',
      sortable: false,
      renderCell: (cellValues) => (
        <Box
          component="span"
          onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'homework', 'Q3')}
          className={cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q3?.weightage
            ? classes.homeworkColor : classes.marksGrey}
        >
          {cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q3?.weightage
            ? Number.isInteger(cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks) ? cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks : Number(cellValues?.row?.homeworkMarks?.Q3?.obtainedMarks).toFixed(2) : '-'}
        </Box>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'bonus',
      headerName: t('BONUS_MARKS'),
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      headerClassName: 'bonusHeader',
      cellClassName: 'bonusCell',
      renderCell: (cellValues) => (
        <Box
          component="span"
          onClick={(e) => setOpenDialog(e, cellValues, 'bonus', null)}
          className={classes.marksGreen}
        >
          {cellValues?.row?.bonus || 0}
        </Box>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: 'grade',
      headerName: t('GRADE'),
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      headerClassName: 'gradeHeader',
      cellClassName: 'gradeCell',
    },
    {
      field: 'gpa',
      headerName: t('GPA'),
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      headerClassName: 'gpaHeader',
      cellClassName: 'gpaCell',
    },
    {
      field: 'annualScore',
      headerName: t('ANNUAL_SCORE'),
      align: 'left',
      sortable: true,
      headerClassName: 'annualHeader',
      cellClassName: 'annualCell',
    },
    {
      field: 'actions',
      headerName: t('ACTIONS'),
      align: 'left',
      sortable: false,
      headerClassName: 'actionHeader',
      cellClassName: 'actionCell',
      renderCell: (row) => (
        <Grid item xs={12} lg={3} display="flex">
          <Tooltip title={t('SEND_EMAIL')}>
            <IconButton
              className={classes.emailIconColor}
              onClick={() => {
                const { manabadiEmail } = row.row.studentInfo;
                const emailParents = [];
                emailParents.push(row?.row?.parent1Info?.personalEmail?.toString());
                emailParents.push(row?.row?.parent2Info?.personalEmail?.toString());
                dispatch({ type: Constant.RECIPIENTS, payload: [manabadiEmail] });
                dispatch({ type: Constant.MAIL_FILTER, payload: 'Student' });
                dispatch({ type: Constant.MAIL_PARENTS, payload: emailParents });
                setLocalStorage('showLocationFilterRecipients', false);
                setLocalStorage('showLocationAnnouncementsRecipients', false);
                setLocalStorage('showSelectAllinEmail', false);
                localStorage.setItem('sendSingleEmail', true);
                navigate(NavigateRoutes.TEACHER_VIEW_EMAIL);
              }}
            >
              <EmailOutlinedIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </Grid>
      ),
    },
  ];
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.studentDetails}>
      {/* {studentsData?.length > 0
        && ( */}
      <DataGridPro
        rows={studentsData}
        columns={columns}
        autoHeight
        disableColumnFilter
        disableColumnSelector
        disableColumnMenu
        disableColumnResize
        disableSelectionOnClick
        disableColumnReorder
        checkboxSelection
        hideFooterRowCount
        hideFooter
        hideFooterSelectedRowCount
        hideFooterPagination
        className={classes.dataGridMyClass}
        components={{
          ColumnUnsortedIcon: CustomUnsortedIcon,
          ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: CustomAscendingIcon,
          ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: CustomDescendingIcon,
        }}
        onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
          setError('');
          const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
          const selectedData = studentsData.filter((row) => selectedIDs.has(row.id));
          checkboxChanged(selectedData);
        }}
        pageSize={100}
        loading={loading}
      />
      {/* )} */}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

This in one of the JSON data

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "dateOfBirth": "2014-10-09T00:00:00.000Z",
  "studentInfo": {
    "firstName": "Chetan reddy",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "12be548432f3",
    "manabadiEmail": "Chetan.12be548432f3@manabadi.siliconandhra.org"
  },
  "parent1Info": {
    "firstName": "Maruthi",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "1e56d8ab18e4",
    "personalEmail": "@gmail.com"
  },
  "parent2Info": {
    "firstName": "Indhira",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "7463913cab45",
    "personalEmail": "@gmail.com"
  },
  "enrolled_courses": [
    {
      "courseId": "24b32206-b67e-4f90-9d81-3cdda3d35641",
      "returningStudent": false,
      "averageScore": 46.5
    }
  ],
  "newReturning": false,
  "marks": {
    "Q1": {
      "obtainedMarks": 0,
      "isAttended": null
    },
    "Q2": {
      "obtainedMarks": 0,
      "isAttended": null
    },
    "Q3": {
      "obtainedMarks": 0,
      "isAttended": null
    }
  },
  "homeworkMarks": {
    "Q1": {
      "obtainedMarks": 0
    },
    "Q2": {
      "obtainedMarks": 0
    },
    "Q3": {
      "obtainedMarks": 0
    }
  },
  "bonus": "",
  "grade": "N/A",
  "gpa": "N/A",
  "annualScore": "46.50",
  "key": 0,
  "profilePhoto": "undefined  ",
  "studentName": "Chetan reddy 12be548432f3  ",
  "studentId": "6dd0c081-1842-49f2-a18b-72dbb226cda6",
  "parentName": "Maruthi 1e56d8ab18e4  ",
  "phoneNumber": "",
  "homeworkQ1": 0,
  "homeworkQ2": 0,
  "homeworkQ3": 0,
  "marksQ1": 0,
  "marksQ2": 0,
  "marksQ3": 0
}
```

[image]

Every field is working except the email.
Can anyone please give any solution?

Comment: Generally it's best to link to a reproducible version of your code, and also to simplify it as much as possible and remove any unneeded code so that others can read the actual problem easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sorting works on the value supplied in `field`, and there's no `studentEmailAddress` field on the object. You could either re-map the email to be flat in line with the other fields, or use [sortComparator](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/sorting/#custom-comparator) to ensure the DataGrid's looking at `row?.studentInfo?.manabadiEmail`